# How can we use notifyAll to ensure that only one thread continues after wakeup?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

From [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://books.google.com/books?id=To3xpkvkPvMC&lpg=PA702&dq=To%20ensure%20that%20only%20one%20thread%20continues%20after%20wake%20up&pg=PA702#v=onepage&q=To%20ensure%20that%20only%20one%20thread%20continues%20after%20wake%20up&f=false), by Scott

> To resume a thread that is suspended on a given object, some other
>   thread must execute the predeﬁned method notify from within a
>   synchronized statement or method that refers to the same object. Like
>   wait, notify has no arguments. In response to a notify call, the
>   language run-time system picks an arbitrary thread suspended on the
>   object and makes it runnable. If there are no such threads, then the
>   notify is a no-op. As in Mesa, it may sometimes be appropriate to
>   awaken all threads waiting in a given object; Java provides a built-in
>   notifyAll method for this purpose.
>
> **If threads are waiting for more than one condition** (i.e., if their waits are embedded in dissimilar loops), there is no guarantee that
>   the “right” thread will awaken. To ensure that an appropriate thread
>   does wake up, the programmer may choose to use notifyAll instead of
>   notify. **To ensure that only one thread continues after wakeup**, the
>   ﬁrst thread to discover that its condition has been satisﬁed must
>   modify the state of the object in such a way that other awakened
>   threads, when they get to run, will simply go back to sleep.
>   Unfortunately, since all waiting threads will end up reevaluating
>   their conditions every time one of them can run, this “solution” to
>   the multiple-condition problem can be quite expensive.

- When using `notifyAll`, all the awaken threads will contend to reacquire the  lock, but **only one** can reacquire the lock,  then return from `wait()` and then reevaluate the condition. So why does it say that "**all** waiting threads will end up **reevaluating their conditions** every time one of them can run"?
- How does the thread, which reacquires the lock and rechecks that the condition become true, "modify the state of the object in such a way that other awakened threads, when they get to run, will simply go back to sleep"?

Thanks.

Comment: `Object.notify()` only wakes up a single thread

Comment: @rollback The book says `notifyAll` not `notify`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why does it say that "all waiting threads will end up reevaluating their conditions every time one of them can run"?

After it will reacquire and release the lock a different thread will aquire it and run. This will continue until they all do that.

> How does the thread, which reacquires the lock and rechecks that the condition become true, "modify the state of the object in such a way that other awakened threads, when they get to run, will simply go back to sleep"?

All the threads will have something like:

```
while (condition) {
    wait();
}
```

The `notifyAll()` caller will set condition to `false` before calling it and then the awakened thread will exit the while loop and before it returns and releases it will do:

```
condition = true;
```

All the other threads will awaken, check the condition, stay in the while loop and call `wait()` (go back to sleep).

Comment: Thanks. In your last two sentences,  how  does an awaken thread  set up `condition = true` so that it can make other awaken thread back to wait? I wonder if any other awaken thread may jump out of the `while(condition)` loop before the awaken thread can set up `condition = true`, so the two awaken threads can continue, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Ben They can't because the awakened thread holds the lock, others threads will awake one at a time only after it will release it.

Comment: Here is my understanding. All awaken threads will resume from the call to `wait()`. Because the call to `wait()` is inside a `synchronized` method, all awaken threads implicitly i.e. automatically reacquired the implicit lock of the `synchronized` method when they wake up, which makes the implicit lock not working. So one of the awaken thread must prevent the other awaken threads from continuing by setting `condition=true` in time to prevent other awaken threads from continuing. How does it set `condition=true` to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `condition = true;` should be called before exiting the synchronized method.

Comment: "They can't because the awakened thread holds the lock, others threads will awake one at a time only after it will release it. " Do you mean only one of the threads waken by `notifyAll()` reacquires the implicit lock of `synchronized`, and the other threads waken by `notifyAll()` do not?

Comment: Only one thread can hold a lock at a time, the others will acquire it only after it will release it.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you should use explicit locking mechanism because it allows you to have **multiple** `conditions and condition queues` for a single lock, which will enable you to use `signal()` instead of `signalAll()`. And that has better performance and less contention.

[Condition API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

Comment: Thanks. Each `Condition` variable has its own condition queue, then do we always use `signal()` and never use `signalAll()`? Does  `signalAll()` notify all the threads waiting on the `Condition` variable? When do we use `signalAll()`?

Comment: It just depends if multiple threads are waiting on the condition and you don't want the case of skipped notification to occur (which can happen though rarely that if the thread can still not proceed because let's say it is waiting on another lock), you would wake all threads using signalAll. the point here is that there are multiple condition queues so there can be multiple wait sets per lock.